# Why can't i extract the actual given name properties in powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
$Results = @()
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Filter\test1.CSV -Header First,Last,Email
Foreach($User in $Users){
    $UserProps = get-aduser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$($user.GivenName)' -and Surname -eq '$($user.Surname)'" -Properties GivenName,Surname,EmailAddress,Department
    $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        FirstName = $User.GivenName
        LastName = $User.Surname
        EmailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
        Department = $UserProps.Department}
}
$Results
```

This is test1.CSV
3 columns include:

First   Last Email

Westley XXX email@email.gov

Dave XXX email@email.gov

Gareth XXX email@email.gov

Paul XXX email@email.gov

What I want it to do is run through the CSV and pull active account information from PowerShell, however I dont think its doing that as my name should be printing out something else

It should be printing out DavidJ as a test since I've edit my account, but instead its printing Dave as my first name how it is in the spreadsheet (CSV).

get-aduser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:2 char:18
+     $UserProps = get-aduser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$($user.GivenName)' -and Sur ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Expected output:

EmailAddress                  FirstName                     Department                    LastName

------------                  ---------                     ----------                    --------

westley@email.gov             westley                       mydepartment                  hislastnamefromAD

david@email.gov               davidj (from AD)              mydepartment                  mylastnamefromAD

gareth@gmail.gov              gareth                        mydepartment                  hislastnamefromAD

paul@gmail.com                paul                          mydepartment                  hislastnamefromAD

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
$Results = @()
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Filter\test1.CSV -Header First,Last,Email
Foreach($User in $Users){
    $UserProps = get-aduser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$($user.GivenName)' -and Surname -eq '$($user.Surname)'" -Properties GivenName,Surname,EmailAddress,Department
    $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        FirstName = $User.GivenName
        LastName = $User.Surname
        EmailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
        Department = $UserProps.Department}
}
$Results
```

You are using $User.GivenName instead of $UserProps. The $User variable is only using what was provided in the csv file. You will need to change the value provided for your custom object to using the return from Active Directory in the form of $UserProps.

```
FirstName = $UserProps.GivenName
```

Comment: Good point, though there are 2 additional problems: `$Users` has only `.First`, `.Last` and `.Email` properties, so the filter won't work as intended and neither will the remaining output properties copied from `$User`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now im getting a completely different error  Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:4 char:5
+     $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @davidjbeiler: That error suggests that you forgot to run `$Results = @()` initially.

Answer (score 0):

Your imported objects have `.First`. and `.Last` properties, yet you're trying to use properties named `.GivenName` and `.SurName` in your `Get-ADUser` `-Filter` argument.

Furthermore, as [Jason's answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44205820/45375), you're trying to populate the result objects from the imported-from-CSV `$User` variable rather than from the queried-from-AD `$UserProps` variable.

These problems have been fixed in this **simpler, more idiomatic reformulation** of your code:

```
$Results = Import-CSV C:\Filter\test1.CSV -Header First,Last,Email |
  Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$($_.First)' -and Surname -eq '$($_.Last)'" -Properties GivenName,Surname,EmailAddress,Department |
    Select-Object @{ l = 'FirstName'; e = 'GivenName' }, 
                  @{ l = 'LastName'; e = 'Surname' }, 
                  EmailAddress, 
                  Department

# Output results.
$Results
```

Comment: @davidjbeiler: I see nothing syntactically wrong with your filter, hence the suggestion to try with _literal_ values to narrow down the problem. If it works with literal values, e.g., `-Filter "GivenName -eq 'David' -and Surname -eq 'Doe'"`, then you know it's the values from the CSV that are the problem.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however it returned nothing, but no errors.  I made sure its what it is exactly from the csv file...

Comment: That implies two unrelated problems: (a) the `$_.First` and `$_.Last` values from your CSV file break the filter and (b) the hard-coded filter values you tried didn't match any user in AD. Jason's answer cannot work, because it uses `$user.GivenName` and `$user.Surname` in the filter, whereas such properties don't exist on `$user` (only the ones specified in the `Import-Csv -Header` parameter exist: `.First`, `.Last`, `.Email`).

Comment: P.S.: I do hope you didn't actually try my suggestion _as-is_, with surname _placeholder_ `Doe`.